¿Cómo puedo generar un acumulado de ventas con MDX de un listado de empleados?
Estaba tratando de hacer un acumulado de ventas de un listado de empleados y me he encontrado con un problema que no sé muy bien cómo resolver correctamente.
Tengo este código, que básicamente genera un listado de empleados con su nombre de aquellos que han generado ventas superiores a 10k y su nombre comienza por "J". Luego listo los nombres en las filas y dos columnas, las ventas y el acumulado escalonado de cada empleado.
WITH SET vips AS
ORDER(
FILTER(empleados.nombre.MEMBERS,
    measures.ventas>10000 AND 
    MID(empleados.nombre.currentmember.name,1,1)='J'
),empleados.nombre.currentmember.name,ASC)
MEMBER measures.rownumber AS 
     RANK(empleados.nombre.currentmember,vips)
MEMBER Acumulado AS
     SUM({vips.ITEM(0):vips.ITEM(measures.rownumber-1)},measures.ventas)

SELECT
    HEAD(vips,5) ON ROWS,
    { 
        Measures.Ventas,
        measures.rownumber,
        measures.Acumulado
     }
    ON COLUMNS
 FROM
    Personal

Al ejecutar este código no me calcula bien el acumulado ya que parece que está cogiendo valores intermedios a pesar de pertenecer a un listado al que se le aplicó un filtrado.

Al analizar la medida de acumulado, me di cuenta que MDX me coge valores intermedios si por ejemplo hago referencia a un conjunto como { vips.item(0):vips.item(3) }, lo cual no entiendo dado que está filtrado bajo unos criterios.
Apliqué este código con las mismas medidas anteriores, y el resultado se puede ver más abajo.
SELECT
{vips.item(0):vips.item(3)} ON ROWS,
{ 
    Measures.Ventas,
    measures.rownumber,
    measures.Acumulado
}
ON COLUMNS
FROM
Personal


Lo solucioné filtrando las posiciones donde la medida rownumber sea diferente de 0, pero me parece poco práctico.
  WITH SET vips AS
    ORDER(
    FILTER(empleados.nombre.MEMBERS,
        measures.ventas>10000 AND 
       MID(empleados.nombre.currentmember.name,1,1)='J'
    ),empleados.nombre.currentmember.name,ASC)
    MEMBER measures.rownumber AS 
      RANK(empleados.nombre.currentmember,vips)
   MEMBER Acumulado AS
       SUM(FILTER({vips.ITEM(0):vips.ITEM(measures.rownumber- 
    1)},measures.rownumber<>0),measures.ventas)

SELECT
    HEAD(vips,5) ON ROWS,
    { 
        Measures.Ventas,
        measures.rownumber,
        measures.Acumulado
    }
ON COLUMNS
FROM
    Personal

Aplicando el criterio anterior sale el resultado correcto, pero no sé si es la mejor forma de hacerlo. Estoy convencido de que hay una manera más fácil de hacerlo sin necesidad de hacer un doble filtrado.

¿Alguien puede indicarme si hay mejor forma de hacerlo?
